# storing a specific field of every products in a collection firebase in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What I am trying to do is read information from "products" collection and from every product there is I want to obtain "total_points" and "total_voting" and save them into 2 const, where i will divide them and find the average rating where I use it somewhere else. I have linked the firebase data in the link below

[Firebase Format Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4liz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [averagePoints, setAveragePoints] = useState(0);
  const [averageVoting, setAverageVoting] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAveragesFromProducts = async () => {
      try {
         const totalVoting = 0;
         const totalPoints = 0;
         const querySnapshot = await 
                         getDocs(collection(db,"products"));
         querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
             const docData = doc.data();
             totalPoints += docData.total_points;
             totalVoting += docData.total_voting;
         });

         totalPoints /= querySnapshot.size;
         totalVoting /= querySnapshot.size;
         setAveragePoints(totalPoints);
         setAverageVoting(totalPoints);
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    getAveragesFromProducts();
  }, []);
  
  return <div>
   Average Points :{averagePoints}
   Average Voting :{averageVoting}
</div>
};
```